# ruby enumerators: immediately skip multiple iterations (or start iterating from n)

Tags: ruby, iterator, continue, skip, enumerator

I'm iterating over permutations of a list (18 items) like this:

```
List = [item0..item18] # (unpredictable)
Permutation_size = 7
Start_at = 200_000_000

for item, i in List.repeated_permutation(Permutation_size).each_with_index
  next if i < Start_at
  # do stuff
end
```

`Start_at` is used to resume from a previously saved state so it's always different but it takes almost **200s** to reach 200 million so I'm wondering if there is a faster way to skip multiple iterations or start at iteration n (converting the enumerator to an array takes even longer). If not, a way to create a custom `repeated_permutation(n).each_with_index` (that yields results in the same order) would also be appreciated.

Feel free to redirect me to an existing answer (I haven't found any)

PS. (what I had come up with)

```
class Array
  def rep_per_with_index len, start_at = 0
    b = size
    raise 'btl' if b > 36
    counter = [0]*len
    # counter = (start_at.to_s b).split('').map {|i| '0123456789'.include?(i) ? i.to_i : (i.ord - 87)} #this is weird, your way is way faster
    start_at.to_s(b).chars.map {|i| i.to_i b}
    counter.unshift *[0]*(len - counter.length)
    counter.reverse!
    i = start_at
    Enumerator.new do |y|
      loop do
        y << [counter.reverse.map {|i| self[i]}, i]
        i += 1
        counter[0] += 1
        counter.each_with_index do |v, i|
          if v >= b
            if i == len - 1
              raise StopIteration
            else
              counter[i] = 0
              counter[i + 1] += 1
            end
          else
            break
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: What is the approximate maximum size of `list`?

Comment: Ideally, I'd like a general solution but right now the size is always 18

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I first construct a helper method, `change_base`, with three arguments:

- `off`, the base-10 offset into the sequence of repeated permutations of the given array `arr`,
- `m`, a number system base; and
- `p`, the permutation size.

The method performs three steps to construct an array `off_m`:

- converts `off` to base `m` (radix `m`);
- separates the digits of the base `m` value into an array; and
- if necessary, pads the array with leading `0`s to make it of size `p`.

By setting `m = arr.size`, each digit of `off_m` is an offset into `arr`, so `off_m` maps the base-10 offset to a unique permutation of size `p`.

```
def change_base(m, p, off)
  arr = off.to_s(m).chars.map { |c| c.to_i(m) }
  arr.unshift(*[0]*(p-arr.size)) 
end
```

Some examples:

```
change_base(16, 2, 32)
  #=> [2, 0]
change_base(16, 3, 255)
  #=> [0, 15, 15]
change_base(36, 4, 859243)
  #=> [18, 14, 35, 31]
18*36**3 + 14*36**2 + 35*36**1 + 31  
  #=> 859243
```

This implementation of `change_base` requires that `m <= 36`. I assume that will be sufficient, but algorithms are available to convert base-10 numbers to numbers with arbitrarily-large bases.

We now construct a method which accepts the given array, `arr`, the size of each permutation, `p` and a given base-10 offset into the sequence of permutations. The method returns a permutation, namely, an array of size `p` whose elements are elements of `arr`.

```
def offset_to_perm(arr, p, off)
  arr.values_at(*change_base(arr.size, p, off))
end
```

We can now try this with an example.

```
arr = (0..3).to_a
p = 2

(arr.size**p).times do |off|
  print "perm for off = "
  print " " if off < 10
  print "#{off}: "
  p offset_to_perm(arr, p, off)
end

perm for off =  0: [0, 0]
perm for off =  1: [0, 1]
perm for off =  2: [0, 2]
perm for off =  3: [0, 3]
perm for off =  4: [0, 1]
perm for off =  5: [1, 1]
perm for off =  6: [2, 1]
perm for off =  7: [3, 1]
perm for off =  8: [0, 2]
perm for off =  9: [1, 2]
perm for off = 10: [2, 2]
perm for off = 11: [3, 2]
perm for off = 12: [0, 3]
perm for off = 13: [1, 3]
perm for off = 14: [2, 3]
perm for off = 15: [3, 3]
```

If we wish to begin at, say, offset 5, we can write:

```
i = 5
p offset_to_perm(arr, p, i)
[1, 1]
i = i.next #=> 6
p offset_to_perm(arr, p, i)
[2, 1]
...
```

Comment: I kind of did the same thing (as an enumerator) but mine is ~6 times slower just at iterating than `[...].repeated_permutation(n).with_index`, did you test the speed?

Comment: I confess I didn't look at your code until just now. Yes, the approaches are quite similar. Since you have working code I suggest you move it from your question to an answer (and preferably add some benchmarks).  I didn't do any performance testing.